# Post Request inside a lambda to public API

Tags: lambda, http-post, vpc, aws-nat-gateway

I'm trying to make HTTP post request inside my Lambda function to call an EC2 public API, that has a container running on it.
I am lost between all the pages on the Internet, so what are the need to achieve getting the response in my lambda to keep doing another logic ?
The Code ?
Configuration to VPC; Nat Gateway ?

![the API call with Post Mann]

([what in this Picture wanna to do inside the lambda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZO3t.png))

I will be thankfully for every idea

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.